# Limit search to posts and pages

Tags: search

I'm adding a search bar to my website, but I want the search bar to only to grab the posts and pages, every time I ask to go to a certain page it makes up a page as an index.php

was just wondering if you knew a solution

```
<?php echo get_search_form( $echo ); ?>
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of search. It's not supposed to take you straight to a single post or page. It's supposed to return a list (or _index_) of results that match your search query. That's what index.php is for: lists of posts/results. You then click on one and it takes you to the single.php view of that page/post.

Answer (score -1):

and add this to functions.php  if you want to search only in posts and pages.
function mk_searchfilter($query) {

```
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('post','page'));
    }
 
return $query;
}
 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','mk_searchfilter');
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer but ive added that, it still goes to /?s=contact but as a new index.php

Comment: hey, i realised its going to index.php instead of single.php, is there a way to change this?

Comment: Yes, you can modify form action but keep in mind then you need to customize a single page. I don't know what are the overall requirements. You can modify form submission in two ways:  lsearchform.php in the child if you are using a child theme.

Comment: function pixel_change_action_value_for_kb_search($param){

 
 
 $param['form_action'] = 'yourpage' ;


 return $param;
}
add_filter('avf_frontend_search_form_param','pixel_change_action_value_for_kb_search'); you can use this filter to modify action..